# The action that failed was LinkDemand

Tags: frameworks

I have an exe file that when execute in the local pc (A) works, but 
when I execute in a network pc (B) it doesn't. The folder where is 
the program is shared with the right permissions. The only thing is
that the network pc (B) isn't in the same IP range that the (A) pc,
but both are in the same domain. I have access from one pc to another
pc.

With another network PC (C) with the same IP range than local pc (A) 
then the exe works.

I made the assembly in that way:

```
create
SET GROUP=Import tool
SET GROUPDESC=Enabling fulltrust to TCImporter assemblies
SET CASPOL=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe
%caspol% -polchgprompt off 
%CASPOL% -m -addgroup All_Code -allcode Nothing -name "%GROUP%" 

-description "%GROUPDESC%"
%CASPOL% -m -addgroup "%GROUP%" -strong -file .\TCImporter.exe 

-noname -noversion FullTrust -name "TCImporter" -description 

"fulltrust to TCImporter.exe" -exclusive on
%CASPOL% -m -addgroup "%GROUP%" -strong -file .\log.dll -noname 

-noversion FullTrust -name "log" -description "fulltrust to log.dll" 

-exclusive on
 %caspol% -polchgprompt on
```

and then the errors that appear in the (B) pc, when I execute the exe
file in the (A) pc  is:

> log:ERROR [FileAppender] Unable to acquire lock on file
>   \lbnf0052\TCImport\log-file.txt.
>
> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>
> Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.
>
> log:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to initialize configuration file
>
> watcher for file [\lbnf0052\TCImport\TCImporter.exe.Config] 
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>
> Request failed. at 
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle
>   rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
>   at
>
> System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   ass emblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, 
>   RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission  permThatFailed)
>
> at
>
> System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet 
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandle  rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction
>   action, Boolean throwException)
>
> at
>
> System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack
>   cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet
>   demands,  RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, Assembly asm, SecurityAction
>   action)
>
> at
>
> log.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatchHandler..ctor(ILoggerRepository
>   repository, FileInfo configFile)
>
> at
>
> log.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(ILoggerRepository
>   repository, FileInfo configFile)
>
> The action that failed was:
>
> LinkDemand
>
> The type of the first permission that failed was:
>
> System.Security.PermissionSet
>
> The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
>
> Intranet (this sometimes is MyComputer when I changed something).

Answer (score 0):

Might be the problem "Allowing Partially Trusted Callers
" described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/02/04/367390.aspx .

Changing your assembly properties as described here http://davedewinter.com/2009/05/21/the-allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute-aptca-6/ might fix it for you.

Also, signing seems to influence the problem.

Plus, .net 4 behaves differently: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336023.aspx.