# The action that failed was: LinkDemand The type of first permission

Tags: c#, networking, permissions, securityexception

I am developing a small exe csharp windows form program that would be executed from network drive.
I understand that using network drive path it would cause security problem.
Therefore, I modify my code but however, when I try to run "Form.Show()", such a simple code also run into trouble:

> The action that failed was: LinkDemand 
>   The type of first permission that failed was: System.Security.PermissionSet 
>   The Zone of assemblythat failed was  Intranet

I wish to solve this problem via any coding method in my app because it is going to be deployed over hundreds of computer where the .NET framework is uncertain. (Might be below .NET framework 3.5 SP1)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215213/the-action-that-failed-was-linkdemand/ ?